# Expand/contract implementation for heavily reused Spring Entity

Tags: java, spring, oop

we would like to extend an existing Spring @Entity with a new set of columns. Depending on a feature flag value the new columns should be used rather than the existing old set (we're expanding the DB schema rather than updating the columns in place as we may need to switch between the two modes for the coming weeks).

The Spring Entity is heavily reused throughout different services.

Example Entity:

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
  ...other columns

  @Column
  String propertyA;

  @Column
  String propertyB;

  public String getPropertyA() { return propertyA; }
  public String getPropertyB() { return propertyB; }
}
```

In the real example there are 3 columns that are being replaced. `getPropertyA` is an existing function that's heavily used (~20-30 calls throughout different services & transformer classes). `getPropertyB` is the newly introduced getter for the new property. Depending on the feature flag status, the application should start using propertyB rather than propertyA.

Is the best approach to introduce the business logic into the entity class via a `getProperty()` class that hides the A/B logic? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This question will likely generate some opinions, but you have nailed the solution already.  Use a single `getProperty()` method that returns the appropriate property value given the feature flag status.

Comment: @lane.maxwell main concern with this was introducing business logic (& the feature flag service) into the Entity class. This seems to be a general anti-pattern. But so far don't see any neat alternative solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering this in response to your question and comment.  As for the business logic, it is not an antipattern to include it with the domain; this is where that logic should reside.  I understand your concern about calling out to the feature service; here's a solution to avoid that, along with why I probably wouldn't do it this way.

You can throw a transient, non-serializable property into the entity where you want this behavior.  The property would hold the value of the feature flag.

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
  @Transient
  @JsonIgnore
  Boolean featureAActive = Boolean.False; // default to false

  @Column
  String propertyA;

  @Column
  String propertyB;

  public String getProperty() {
     return featureAActive ? propertyA : propertyB;
  }
}
```

In your service method, where you hydrate the entity, set the flag to a value corresponding to the feature.  Psuedo code here to give you a rough idea.

```
public SomeEntity getSomeEntity() {
  SomeEntity someEntity = SomeEntityRepository.findById(12L);
  someEntity.setFeatureAActive(featureService.isFeatureActive("MY_FEATURE");
  return someEntity;
}
```

Now, the downside to using this approach is this.  Once you create that Entity and set the flag, as long as it's in memory, it will use the value set when you created it.  This is not ideal because that feature could be turned off/on, but you'll only ever have the state that it was in during creation.

For this reason, I would not put this logic into the entity, but I'd push it up to the consumer.  Where those properties are consumed, let them query the feature.  Psuedo code again, assume that the output from `myFeatureManager.isActive("MY_FEATURE")` is a boolean value representing the state of the feature.

```
String thePropertyValueDrivenByTheFeatureFlag = myFeatureManager.isActive("MY_FEATURE") ? someEntity.getPropertyA() : someEntity.getPropertyB();
```